# what does dot and net means?

Tags: asp.net

What is the meaning of dot in asp.net and what is the meaning of net?

Comment: Dot is a dot and net is a net.

Comment: It means, as ever, that Microsoft's marketing department is the worst one in the history of marketing. I am surprised they haven't introduced technologies such as 'the', 'a', 'god', 'hi'

Comment: @adolf Actually, Bill Gates is the most genius marketing person to ever walk the face of the planet, and the rest of the marketing department is pretty good as well.

Comment: In that case, walk up to a member of the public and ask them to explain the difference between "windows 8" and "windows RT"

Answer (score 1):

## [Microsoft .Net Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx)